# How to update the state of a bottom navigation bar from NavigatorObserver?

Tags: flutter, state-management

I'm creating a bottom navigation bar and everything works fine except when the user presses the back button on their device. The state of the navigation bar doesn't update to reflect the page they're on. To fix this, I found out about `NavigatorObserver`. Now I can see when a route gets popped but I have no way of updating the state. My navigation bar uses routes so when a user taps a button, it'll push a new route. I'm trying to update the index of the navigation bar but I can't see a way to do so. The navbar is using a `StatefulWidget` so I can use the `setState` callback.

I've tried using keys but I can't re-use them since they're on different `Scaffold`s. I can't access the `BuildContext` from a `NavigationObserver` so I can't use things like `Provider` to notify a change and to rebuild.

```dart
class CustomBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomBottomNavBarState createState() => _CustomBottomNavBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavBar> {
  static int _selectedIndex;
  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;
  set selectedIndex(int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = newIndex;
    });
  }

  //...
}
```

```dart
class NavBarObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    final navBarRoutes = Routes.all.sublist(0,4);
    final routeName = route.settings.name;
    if (navBarRoutes.contains(routeName)) {
      final index = navBarRoutes.indexOf(routeName);
      // selectedIndex = index;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it couple ways. Here I have given an example with `ValueNotifier`. First you can create a enum that define different pages of you bottom navigation bar. Then you create a `ValueNotifier` with your enum type and share it between `NavBarObserver` and `CustomBottomNavBar`. In `NavBarObserver` when any tab change occurred you simply updated the `ValueNotifier` value with corresponding tab's enum value. You can listen `ValueNotifier` value change in `_CustomBottomNavBarState` to update the bottom navigation bar state.

```
enum Tabs{one, two, three}

class CustomBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<Tabs> tabsChangeNotifier;

  CustomBottomNavBar(this.tabsChangeNotifier);

  @override
  _CustomBottomNavBarState createState() => _CustomBottomNavBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavBar> {
  Tabs _currentTab;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.tabsChangeNotifier.addListener(() {
       setState(() {
         _currentTab = widget.tabsChangeNotifier.value;
       });
    });
    }
  }


class NavBarObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  final ValueNotifier<Tabs> tabsChangeNotifier;

  NavBarObserver(this.tabsChangeNotifier);

  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    final navBarRoutes = Routes.all.sublist(0,4);
    final routeName = route.settings.name;
    if (navBarRoutes.contains(routeName)) {
      tabsChangeNotifier.value = Tabs.two;
      // selectedIndex = index;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume I can just use an integer instead of an enum though, right?

Comment: And where do I create the ValueNotifier, both widgets take one.

Comment: You can use any type. Any way Dart enum value is integer. It depends on the app structure. You should create ValueNotifier  moment you create BottomNavigation bar and  NavBarObserver.